# Slow application - Visual Studio 2015: How to find the expensive methods/functions (most time consuming)

Tags: debugging, sharepoint, visual-studio-2015, performance-testing, visual-studio-debugging

I have a large and complex SharePoint 2013 Solution and on my development machine Visual Studio 2015 installed. The application is extremely slow, opening in Internet Explorer takes >20 seconds. Now i would like to find to find out which part of my code is the part which needs so long. It is nothing what i can do by going step by step through the code cause it is a really large project. What can i do to find this out?

Comment: Did you see network tab in F12 developer  window(Chrome) ..my suggestion is to start from there.. its your code some thing else taking time

Comment: Yes, of course. But it takes more than > 15 until the browser get a response and then it starts executing the JS files. But the first 15 seconds there happens something on the server side code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem by using SharePoint Developer Dashboard and using [SPMonitoredScope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff512758(v=office.14).aspx). With this i was able to see which methods/functions where called and in which frequency and how many time was consumed for this.

```
using (new SPMonitoredScope("My Scope Name"))
{
   doSomeWork(); 
}
```